# Как переименовать файлы через cmd?

Tags: cmd

Допустим есть файлы

```
file1-min.jpg
file2-min.jpg
file3-min.jpg
```

нужно чтобы было

```
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
```

это нужно использовать маску в цикле?
**P.S.**
Подскажите, как решить данную задачу?
И сильно ли будет отличаться решение, если маску нужно будет переставить в начало файла?
**P.S.**
добавлю, что файлы могут называться по разному в одной папке, т.е. не обязательно в начале будет `file`, нужно удалить `-min` у всех файлов

**P.S,**
такой вариант правильный?

```
@echo off
for %%A IN (*.jpg,*.png) DO (
 for /f "tokens=1* delims='-min'" %%B IN ("%%~A") DO ren %%~A %%~B%%~xA
)
echo on
```

Comment: Да, можно использовать маску в цикле. Можно не использовать.

Comment: @Эникейщик, подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Да я там сам только ``cd`` и ``dir`` умею :)

Comment: У вас имена файлов различаются только одним символом?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, файлы могут быть такие: `file2-min.jpg`, `asfdsf-min.jpg` `dddddd-min.png` подскажите, как правильно сделать?

Comment: кто нибудь подскажет, как это сделать?

Comment: Поставьте `echo` вместо `ren` внутри цикла - посмотрите какие маски сгенерировались.

Comment: @nick_n_a, маску посмотреть как-то так? `for /f "tokens=1* delims='-min'" %%B IN ("%%~A") DO @echo %%B` выводится только первый символ имени файла

Comment: неужели сложно подсказать?

Comment: так в echo нужно написать ваши `@echo ren %%~A %%~B%%~xA` и вы увидите какие маски сгенерировались.

Comment: задача достаточно нетривиальная, врядли быстро и правильно тут подскажут. Через  echo можно найти свои ошибки.

Comment: @nick_n_a, посмотрел маску, и что дальше? `f.jpg`

Comment: Маска эта верная?

Comment: нет не верная, я поэтому и спрашиваю как-бы помощи, если вы обратили внимание

Comment: Тогда правьте маску.

Comment: а как правильно её поправить? с масками мало работал

Answer (score 1):

```
ren file?*.jpg file?.*
```

`?` для одного символа, который не будет меняться после после переименования, первая `*` для части, которая будет исключена, вторая `*` для сояранения суффикса `jpg`.

Comment: обновил вопрос,